# cual es la contraseña root por defecto?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

hice una instalacion de mariadb mediante homebrew --> brew install mariadb, lo cual instalo correctamente, pero el tema esta en que cuando quiero acceder desde el terminal al mysql con el comando: mysql -h localhost -u root -p me pedira logicamente el user root pero este no lo configure ni me brindo al finalizar la instalacion por lo cual solo tengo acceso al mysql ejecutando el comando: mysql, pero por localhost/phpmyadmin me pide el usuario root que es lo que no se, se instalo en una iMac m1 monterrey.

incluso trate colocar el comando : mysql_secure_installation pero me pide el  current password que es el que no se cual es.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: utilice este comando: SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('clave')
ahora por consola : mysql -h localhost -u root -p ya tengo acceso pero por localhost/phpmyadmin me da error: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory ---- el servidor mysql no autorizo su acceso

Comment: Prueba sin `-p`.

Comment: @Sal si quito el -p me da error...